# How to send a string from one android emulator to another emulator in different device?

Tags: android, sockets, android-emulator, genymotion

I need to send a string from emulator A in laptop L1 to emulator B in laptop L2 using intranet (NOT INTERNET). These systems will be connected to same wifi. Tried with socket programming,multicast,google near by but none of them are working in emulator (Working in real device). Installed genymotion and tried to use bridged adapter but then *geny* emulator is not connecting to wifi. for that also followed all the top answers provided in SO(No luck).

Looked for port forwarding also but not helping.

Hence, I need a working code to achieve this.

Comment: Take it one step at a time. The first step is to send something from the host to the emulator.

Comment: Achieved running server in pc and running the client in another pc -> emulator able to send data. Now I tried with sending data from emulator(server app) to host pc then the client app in host pc will receive the string. But it's not receiving . Any suggestion? @JamesKPolk